# Does an update with an empty Map count bandwidth in firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have this db:

```
Root
 \
 users
   \
   uid
     \
     name: "Ivan"
     \
     token: "-Mfwfeqqeqtyyetw"
```

To update token I use:

```
val map = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
map["token"] = -Mrw-eoifpeoghqgop"
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/$uid").updateChildren(map)
```

Which works fine. My question is, if I comment `map["token"] = "-Mrw-eoifpeoghqgop"` and I perform the update with an empty Map, does it count when it comes to billing? Is the update operation still performed, or is not, as the Map is empty? In the console nothing is highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the Firebase [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing), you'll see that the Realtime Database only charges for download bandwidth (so bandwidth consumed for reading data) and storage. There is no charge by Firebase for upload bandwidth, nor for write operations.